# Create multiple layouts from JSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask

I am attempting to parse a `JSON` response from a `PHP` file and then use the data to create a series of `RadioButton`, `EditText`, `CheckBox`, and `DropDownMenu` elements inside a layout. In other words a dynamic or "on the fly" layout. I'm currently receiving the `JSON` I need but the app is crashing.

**AsyncTask**

```
    class LoadAllQuestions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray questions = null;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading questions. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting JSON string from URL
            companyName = cn.getText().toString();
            projectName = pn.getText().toString();
            String componentName = (String) ab.getSelectedTab().getText();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", companyName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", projectName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("component",
                    componentName));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                    nameValuePairs);

            // Check your log cat for JSON response
            Log.d("All Questions: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found: getting Array of Questions
                    questions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTIONS);

                    // looping through All Questions
                    for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = questions.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each JSON item in variable
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String field = c.getString(TAG_FIELD);
                        String value = c.getString(TAG_VALUE);
                        Result result = null;
                        if (field == r) {
                            result = new Result();
                            result.setType(1);
                            result.setName(name);
                            result.setField(field);
                            result.setValue(value);

                        } else {
                            result = new Result();
                            result.setType(2);
                            result.setName(name);
                            result.setField(field);
                            result.setValue(value);
                        } 
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    Log.v("ERROR", "No JSON for you!");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Result result = new Result();
            if (result.getType() == 1) {
                LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.genA_layout);
                // create
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
                rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(getActivity());                
                RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton(getActivity());               
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

                // set
                rb.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                rb2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                rb.setText(result.getValue());
                rb2.setText(result.getValue());
                tv.setText(result.getName());
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                // add
                rg.addView(rb);
                rg.addView(rb2);
                ll.addView(tv);
                ll.addView(rg);
                content.addView(ll);
            } else if (result.getType() == 2) {
                // find
                LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.genA_layout);
                // create
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());              
                EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());
                LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                // set
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                ll1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv.setText(result.getName());
                ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                // add
                ll1.addView(tv);
                ll1.addView(et);
                content.addView(ll1);
            }

            // find
            LinearLayout loader = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.loader_layout);
            Button save = (Button) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.generalAssets_save_button_ID);
            // set
            loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        };
    }
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "display_name": "Store #",
            "field_type": "Text Field",
            "option_value": ""
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Address",
            "field_type": "Text Field",
            "option_value": ""
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Type of Business",
            "field_type": "Drop Down Menu",
            "option_value": "Education\r\nHealth\r\nComputers\r\nFood\r\nRetail\r\nOther"
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Is this business good?",
            "field_type": "Radio",
            "option_value": "Yes\r\nNo"
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Are they nice people?",
            "field_type": "Check Box",
            "option_value": "Yes\r\nNo"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

**Result Class**

```
public class Result {
    private String name;
    private String field;
    private String value;
    private int type;

    //constructor
    public Result() {

    }

    // <-----SET METHODS----->
    public void setName(String name) {
        name = this.name;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        field = this.field;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        value = this.value;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        type = this.type;
    }   

    // <-----GET METHODS----->
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

If you would like the `XML` just ask.

**Edit**
Edited my post from suggestions. Thanks @Ken Wolf. The errors are gone but now my fragment is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you shouldn't be changing the UI in `doInBackground`.

Can't you encapsulate everything you need in some kind of transfer Object, set the result accordingly, and do everything in `onPostExecute`?

Example:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
  ...
  Result result = null;
  if (field == r) {
    result = new Result();
    result.setType(1);
    result.setValue(value);
    result.setName(name);
    ... // store whatever else you need
  }
  else {
    result.setType(2);
    ... // store whatever else you need
  }
  return result; 
}

protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
  if (result.getType() == 1)
    // build layout
  else if (result.getType() == 2)
    // build layout
}
```

Of course, make the `Result` class more meaningful to you and your data.

Comment: That's definitely a possibility I hadn't thought of. Would you care to take a stab at writing the code for that?

Comment: It does, you want me to essentially create a `method` that returns `Result` and make the scope cover my `if-else` statements. Now that is the `Result` from the `javax.transform.xml` library, correct?

Comment: Well, `Result` would it's own class that you make, not from any existing library - responsible for encapsulating all the data you need. So it's a class that has fields of strings, etc, whatever it is you need. It's sole purpose is just to hold information for you to access later. Call it whatever you like :)

Comment: Ha, nevermind I misread the code, you actually want me to instantiate an object called Response and then return that, sorry. There are 3 libraries that actually hold built in methods called "Response". I was just overthinking it. Yes makes perfect sense. I will test it and let you know

Comment: I edited my post, the errors are gone but my screen is blank except the save button I make visible

Comment: You need to set layout parameters on all your views. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views)

Comment: edited post again.. still blank. Could it be `Result` is not returning any values? Or is it that when I create new `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT))` I should be setting it to `ll` or `ll1.layoutParams`

Comment: See @torbenkohlmeier's answer. You're not using the `Result` you built..You need to change your AsyncTask to `extends AsyncTask<String, String, Result>` and return Result...currently you return `null`...

Comment: We are on the same page, I was just about to say that. It's time for a new question if I can't figure this out. Thanks Ken, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new (empty) Result object in onPostExecute. You need to use the Result object you created in doInBackground, for example by adding a Result field in the AsyncTasc, assign it in doInBackground and use it in onPostExecute.

**Edit:** If you are not using the parameter file_url in inPostExecute, you should change it to Result and return the result object in doInBackground.