# Is it possible in Android that each row from the query will create button?

Tags: android, android-button

We're making an app that can make surveys which is to be answered, of course.

But i'm not sure if it is possible that, for example, we will display all the list of inserted survey topics

and that in every topic, there'll be 1 button for each, generated individually ( sorry for the term. not really good in English. ) so that they can select it.

I'm also hoping to use it in the list of questions so that they can select from given answers using those buttons.

If it is possible, can you please give me some hints/starting lines how to make it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, but I think that ListView might be a good place to start.

Comment: I've already managed to display the list of items from the query, though. Is it a start?

Comment: or you can sketch out your user interface so we can imagine how you want your app looks like?

Comment: I'm thinking about something like a for loop that each result will make a button, like in VB.Net.

Comment: It is not clearly, what result do you mean? Result of what?

Comment: E.g , my query is to select all from table 'Users'.
Then the query returns 4 rows, each listed in the ListView.
What I want is that each row, there's a button created, meaning there should be 4 buttons all in all.

Comment: then you can create a custom layout for listview with button in it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to overview [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) widget of Android first.
It helps to show lists you want.

And after you need to research [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) you need. It is interface you must implement to use with `ListView`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already displayed the data by using the ListView. What's the next thing I should do?

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what do you need to show? i am not sure I understand right.. You need to show list, each element has button, and you want to programmatically generate this button?

Comment: Yup. Each item in the ListView should atleast generate buttons, 'programmatically' (as you described).

Comment: If you need to generate `Button` programmatically. You can add new view (`Button` extends `View`) and add it to layout of your list item.
You can read this question for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views
Hope it helps.

Comment: Should I drag-and-drop a 'button' from the palette or just code it in the XML? Sorry for asking. Really bad when it comes to XMLs.\

Comment: It is not really important in what way you whant to describe xml file for your list item. Result is equal. I have described programmatically creating view. It is not both you mentioned.