# TextVisibility change after a period of time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

, I have just started learning java for android, I have set the TextVisibility of a textfield to GONE, I need the TextVisibilty to change to VISIBLE after 7 seconds from Button click, I had searched the internet and could not find anything useful or I could'nt understand. So, Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android, when you want something to be executed after some period of time and in other thread you generally use a **Handler** like so:

```
final TextView yourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextId);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()) {
@Override
    public void run() {
        yourText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 7000);
```

If you want, you could implement the Runnable class in your Activity, so you don't have to encapsulate anything:

```
public class MyActivity implements Runnable
```

And then you pass **this** to de postDelayed method first argument,

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 7000);
```

and implement the run method inside your activity:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.id.your_layout);
    /* some code */
}

@Override
public void run() {
    yourText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This will execute the code inside the run method after the period of time you set in the second argument of postDelayed, and inside another thread, so you could continue to make things inside your MainActivity like clicking buttons or something else.

EDIT with sample code for comments:

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
Handler handler2 = new Handler();
handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    tvt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}, 7000);
handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    tvt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}, 12000);
```

Comment: Another help dude, can I play a audio track after a period of time, If yes, Can you please help me ?

Comment: @Kdvinmk The logic to play after a period of time is just the same, just put what you want to do inside the run method. I don't have the knowledge on how to handling audio since I'm kind of new to android, but you should get it from developers site, there's a section of training for [Managing Audio Playback](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/index.html).

Comment: Thank you!! If iI want to add another text after 12 seconds, its just follow this again right ?

Comment: Yes, just change 7000 to whatever time you want in milliseconds, in that case, 12000.

Comment: I tried that but its not working. My code:
http://gyazo.com/bce4d6da418ba9873da8edb1de8c8da1

Comment: tvt2 is another textView? In this case you're just changing it's visibility and not "adding" another textView. If you want to add it programmatically you could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views).

Comment: Please can you explain me about this ? sorry fr the trouble, the first textview is changing its visibility after 7 seconds, like that i want another textview to channge its visibility after 12 seconds

Comment: Assuming you've already the textViews referecens in your code, try to use the code a posted on the answer to create a handler and use the postDelayed method on it instead of doing it directly from the view like tvt.postDelayed. Also, create 2 handlers, one for each task. It should work. I'll edit my answer post with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
final TextView yourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextId);
yourText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
yourText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 7 * 1000);
```

in your button click listener.
For example, in OnCreate() of your activity:

```
final TextView yourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextId);
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                yourText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                yourText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        yourText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
               }, 7 * 1000);
               }
        });
```

Comment: Another help dude, can I play a audio track after a period of time, If yes, Can you please help me ?