# How can I identify a TextView with a Number as ID?

Tags: java, android

I have an ID of a TextView created by a GridView Adapter. Now I want to define my TextView with my ID.

```
TextView myTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.5);
myTextView.setText("exampleText");
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error only says it expected a ")" and ";" because it doesnt accept the number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385604/android-findviewbyid-use-int-at-id-field

Comment: yeah, I have read it but it didnt work the id i got was the same number "5" and not an ID like "R.id.5". I tried intializing the Textview with this id but the app crashed.

Comment: Can you not give it a String value?

Comment: `@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // 1
        final String day = days[position];

        // 2
        if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendarday, null);
        }

        final TextView calTag = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cal_tag);

        calTag.setText(day);

        return convertView;
    }`

Comment: thats the getView function of my Adapter. Can i set there a new id to the textView?

Answer (score 0):

FindViewById method is looking for an id in the inflated view, not creating/assigning a new one.
Further more, resource name must begin with a character, you can't name it starting with a number.