# How to set the dynamic data when button clicks to add inflate layout in android

Tags: android, button, layout, android-inflate

How to set the dynamic data when button clicks to add inflate layout text and imageview in android?

Comment: set data to where ?!

Comment: "Dynamically add views" is what you're at I think. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2395769/715593).

Comment: can you please be a little more specific?