# Creating CardView at run time does not work?

Tags: android

I've the following code:

```
CardView card = new CardView(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CardView), null, 0);
card.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
));
resultsLayout.addView(card);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/resultsLayout"
    tools:context="com.xyz.ResultsActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

But this does not display the card? Can anyone please help?

Comment: What's your `parentLayout`? Is it a Relative, Linear or some other Layout? Also where's your LayoutParams?

Comment: It is a linearLayout. I don't have any layoutParams

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views) to do it properly.

Comment: @Vucko see the updated code. No success yet

Comment: Is there anything else in the LinearLayout? Show the xml plz.

Comment: @Vucko Please see update XML. thanks a lot :)

Comment: You used LinearLayout params, but your view is a RelativeLayout

Comment: This is not a Linear, but a RelativeLayout :P Try adjusting the LayoutParams.

Comment: @Vucko even with those changes, there is no progress.

Comment: Try changing Relative to Linear Layout and returning the params back to the previous state.