# How do I add a view to a viewParent programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, view, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an xml layout file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/homeCoordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivitys.ViewPager.Fragments.Home">
    <com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView
        android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_dashboard_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to add a view to the container of the pulltorefresh programmatically, I have added it to my coordinator as shown below but I do not know how to add it to my pulltorefresh any ideas?

```
 CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout=(CoordinatorLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.homeCoordinatorLayout);
        ImageView imageView=new ImageView(getActivity());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ufo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
coordinatorLayout.addView(imageView);
```

**Edit***
If you would like to know more on the subject you can find it here:
1. [ViewManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html) Official Documentation.
2. Straight forward [Tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html) about how to add all kinds of views by Mysamplecode.
3. Related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views) on the subject to prevent common misunderstandings.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13490799)

Comment: @SuhailMehta , Agree! Sometimes I'm being to simple.