# Adding a view when a spinner item is selected

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner. If selected item is (e.g) 1, then add EditText with button. I used switch method to check item_name. What you recommend in adding edittext with button? Is it a good way to create new layout? How can i add layout to screen?

Comment: Here is how you can add views https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your initial layout create a container layout to inflate with your desired generated views.

```
<RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create the separate layouts (your_layout) that you want to generate upon spinner selection. When that happens, use a layout inflator to replace the container with the layout you want.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, false);
View container = inflater.inflate(R.id.container, null, false);
container.addView(layout);
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about inflater.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener).

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}
```

});

Comment: Use @Nikos Hidalgo 's answer to add views when item is selected