# How can I clone views using java code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I copy/clone a views automatically in android studio
for example, I have one imageview and a textview. how can i clone them on runtime with different values alongside with existing objects like them.

I tried to make invisible views and and update them later. but I don't think its efficient way. plus it is also limited

I'm fetching data from JSON file. which will get a text description and an image link each time I update that file online. so I want to update that in android app too! but unfortunately I can't do with single textview and single imageview. so need to automatically make them whenever the data is updated online.

if there is any other way of cloning views. kindly tell me.

Comment: You should try rephrasing this if you want helpful answers. Add some code and maybe a more specific question.

Comment: you are probably looking for a recycler view https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: this might help [how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all read this [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , it's really hard to understand what you want us to help you with.

If i understand you correctly you want to display some kind of a list that updates when u update your JSON/Online database.

If that's the case I think the best way to go is [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)
it's basically an efficient way to create a dynamic list that can be updated at runtime

And here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-recyclerview-tutorial/) you can use