# How do I access a textview from a custom xml file?

Tags: java, android

I would like to access a textview called user_status that's inside a custom  xml layout file in order to populate it with some data. I would like to access it from  my main activity java class. How do I do this? I have tried some answers already on stack overflow but it's either not working or too outdated.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = MessageActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row, null);
                    TextView userMessage= (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
                    userMessage.setText("NEW MESSAGE DUMMMY!");
```

Comment: what data you want to populate the textview with? JSON, a data array?, Please provide more info and code that you already tried please

Comment: I would just like to populate it with a simple string data.

Comment: share what u tried yet......

Comment: ` TextView t =findViewById(R.id.t);
                t.setText(String.valueOf(list.size()));`    This is code to set a textview with data from a list try removing the inflater and just using it as a plain normal texxtview

Comment: Check your ID of the textview, change it to something simple and try the code you have also remove the (TextView) you have its unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
TextView userMessage = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
userMessage.setText("NEW MESSAGE DUMMMY!");
```

Comment: The Id of the text view is user_status so i don't think that will work

Comment: First he used this id, now change

Comment: Yes I see that now

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in your MainActivity, you should **add view** first then find TextView or you may **include your custom layout** file in your MainActivity's xml layout.

Add View can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views)

include layout can find [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)