# How do I create a new TextView and display it? (with programming)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm still new to Android Studio, and for practice I want to make a simple To-Do list app. I'm troubles with creating a new TextView and displaying it.

I know that I probably need to manually insert the TextView into the layout, but I have no idea how to do that.

Here's my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button submitBtn;
    EditText userInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
        userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.submitBtn) {
            String userInputString = userInput.getText().toString();
            TextView listItem = new TextView(this);
            listItem.setText(userInputString);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using ConstraintLayout for my layouting. If somebody could help guide me to the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Programmatically Add Views to Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, you get your `ConstraintLayout` using its ID and then call `addView(View)` with your `TextView` as the parameter on it.
Assuming your `ConstraintLayout` has the id `myLayout`:

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
layout.addView(listItem);
```