# Android Studio Add text view on button click

Tags: java, android

So i'm trying to create a java app for tracking orders, and I need each button to create a view in an ordered list currently i'm just trying to get the first button to add information but it isn't doing anything. Any help would be appreciated as I am very new to android programming.

```
Section of code in activity main that contains the linear layout and button i want to be able to add views
```

> ```
> <Button
> android:id="@+id/add_funnel_cake"
> android:layout_width="90dp"
>         android:layout_height="80dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>         android:paddingRight="10dp"
>         android:text="Funnel Cake"></Button>
> ```

Layout resource file with view i want to add

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/funnelItem"
>     android:layout_width="387dp"
>     android:layout_height="40dp"
>     android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
>     android:text="Funnel Cake"
>     android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
>     android:textSize="25dp"></TextView>
> ```

Section of code within MainActivity for functionality

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
> View.OnClickListener {
> LinearLayout orderList;
> Button buttonFunnel;
> Button buttonOreo;
> Button buttonTwinkie;
> Button buttonSnicker;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     orderList = findViewById(R.id.Order_List);
>     buttonFunnel = findViewById(R.id.add_funnel_cake);
>     buttonFunnel.setOnClickListener(this);
> }
> @Override
> public void onClick(View v){
>     addFunnelCake();
> }
>
> private void addFunnelCake(){
>     View funnel = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.funnel_cake_row, null, false);
>     TextView funnelCake = (TextView)funnel.findViewById(R.id.funnelItem);
>     /*
>     ImageView closeItem = (ImageView)funnel.findViewById(R.id.remove_item);
>     */
>
>     orderList.addView(funnel);
> }
> ```

I'm sorry for the copy pasted code this is my first stack overflow post I have embedded screen shots below they are in the same order the code is copy pasted in if it makes it easier, any help is much appreciated!

[First copy pasted code ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USsbk.png)

[Second copy Pasted code ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhac2.png)

[Third copy pasted screenshot first half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8liZ9.png)
[Third copy pasted screenshot second half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK1aW.png)

> 2022-05-23 16:23:56.968 19935-19935/com.example.funnel_cake_tracker
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.funnel_cake_tracker, PID: 19935
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5106)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4935)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4875)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4848)
> at com.example.funnel_cake_tracker.MainActivity.addFunnelCake(MainActivity.java:45)
> at com.example.funnel_cake_tracker.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
> at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to inflate the View you want to add differently.

```
View inflatedView = View.inflate(context, yourViewXML, null); //use null to not add View to parent
```

Solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24411058/17799032

Comment: what should i be using as the context here I've tried null, orderList.getContext(), this.getApplicationContext(), and getApplicationCOntext() all of these result in the program crashing  Here is a copy paste of how i have the code currently Context context = getApplicationContext();
        View funnel = View.inflate(context, R.layout.funnel_cake_row, orderList);

Comment: As your code is inside an `Activity`, you can just pass itself as the context: View.inflate(this, R.layout.funnel_cake_row, orderList);

Comment: I also tried that and it still leads to crashing. So it must be somewhere else thats causing it. Thank you for the assisstance i really appreciate it!

Comment: If you add the stack trace of the crash to your post we can have a look at it. Or maybe its a new question, I don't know :D

Comment: I believe i added the stack trace to my post!

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem: `View.inflate(context, yourViewXML, yourLinearLayout);` . Here I already added the `View` to a parent...I think: ` View.inflate(context, yourViewXML, null);` should fix it. I also updated my answer.

Comment: Yes it is now working thank you so much I really appreciate the help! I would have fixed it sooner but i didnt realize i had to hit show more comments lol.