# How to add a layout piece to a scroll view from code in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, view, fragment

My app has two fragments and a menu at the bottom with two options to switch the views and a plus button. The first view (the second is not important (empty by now)) is containing a scrollView and I want to be able to add with the plus button some rectangle things defined in a layout file with a class they should be added one under the other.
[image: The app look]
[image: The area I would like to add is highlighted in blue]
The first picture shows the apps look, the second one shows the area I would like to add (it's highlighted in blue).
I don't know  how to add that thing to the view neither am I atempting it correctly.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working?

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, I can only set it as a full layout, but I can't add multiple ones from code.

Comment: You're not answering the question I asked - what have you tried so far to solve this problem for yourself and what is it that is not working for you? The clearer you can be about what the root problem is, the easier it will be to get help to get you going.

Comment: The only thing I've done is inflating the view because I don't know how to add it to the fragment.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're aiming at sounds like what the **[RecyclerView](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview/)** component provides.

It's specifically made for adding a dynamic amount of sub-views to a scrollable view "container". In other words, adding as many items to a scrollable list as you wish.

Please do notice that RecyclerView isn't favoured by modern development standards, but then again, the entire View system has it's faults and you're not here for a lecture on Jetpack Compose... *(This is a soft hint at the fact that many people dislike recycler views for their relative complexity, but they solve the specific problem you describe.)*

Please also be aware that the usage isn't exactly straightfoward if you're a beginner. It's still easier than learning a different UI framework though.

And you already have the correct idea to define a layout for your child items that you want to add to the parent "container" layout.

So first of all, you need to replace your scroll view with a recycler view.

*(If you're keen on sticking with your scroll view idea, then you need to add a sub *LinearLayout* to it. The ScrollView won't position your child elements one after another, it's not made for that. LinearLayouts are what you're looking for, in that case.)*

You also need to define the **ViewHolder** and the **Adapter** (see the [example I linked above](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview/) for usage). They have the job of linking views to properties and the child items to the parent list.

While the usage might be complex at first sight (and the recycler view comes with it's own special set of issues you might encounter later on), you'll probably write just as much, if not more code, if you code your own custom solution, as you go along.